# drop first word if string doesn't start with space Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to drop the first word if the string doesn't start with space

using filter or map or dropWhile etc...

if it starts with space keep everything

example:

dropw "i like" -> " like"

dropw " i like" -> " i like"

This is how i tried:

```
dropw (x:xs)
 | isSpace x = (x:xs)
 | otherwise = dropWhile not(xs == " ") (x:xs)
```

but it doesn't like the (xs == " ") part,idk how else could i do it

Answer (score 3):

You just need this:

```
dropw = dropWhile (/= ' ')
```

To explain in a bit more detail: a `String` in Haskell is simply a list of characters. Character literals are written with single quotes, as opposed to string literals which use double quotes. Your description of what the function wants to do amounts to "get rid of all the non-space characters at the start of the string", which is exactly what [dropWhile](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?q=dropWhile&hoogle=dropWhile) does, when specialised to strings and characters.

You don't need to explicitly test if the first character is a space, because `dropWhile` takes care of that. You also have some syntax issues, because `dropWhile not(xs == " ") (x:xs)` means to call `dropWhile` with 3 arguments: the function `not`, the expression `xs == " "` and the list (string) `x:xs` - which unsurprisingly will cause a variety of type errors.